# Остается шлейф при перетаскивании || SAFARI & Sortable (JQuery)

Tags: сортировка, jquery-ui, safari

При перетаскивании остается **шлейф** (**Только на Safari**). Кто знает, в чем может быть **причина**?

Код:

```
$(query).sortable({
            connectWith: '.component-task-column',
            items: '.component-card-task',
            cancel: '.loading-files, .task-content-editing .title-edit[contenteditable="true"], .task-content-editing, .selected, .task-board-head, .component-task-column-add, .closedButton, .optionsButton, .task-info-element, .task-info-line-item',
            start: async function (event, ui) {
                ui.placeholder.height(114);
                ui.placeholder.width(ui.item[0].clientWidth);
                ui.placeholder[0].style.background = 'var(--hover)';

                ui.item[0].classList.add('dragged');
            },
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ui.item[0].classList.remove('dragged');
               
            },
            revert: 100,
            distance: 0.5,
            dropOnEmpty: true,
            placeholder: "component-card-task-placeholder"
        });
```

Стили карточки:

```
    .component-card-task {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  z-index: 12;

  background: var(--white);
  border: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0.3px 0.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
  0 1.6px 3.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  border-radius: 4px;

  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: fit-content;
  min-height: -moz-fit-content;

  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;

  position: relative;

  & .moreOptionsFromCard {
    display: none;
  }

  & .component-task-item {
    &.mini {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

      & .drag-selector,
      & .component-task-item-actions,
      & .sorting-tab-priority,
      & .sorting-tab-tags,
      & .component-task-item-right {
        display: none;
      }

      & .sorting-tab-users {
        margin-left: 4px;
      }

      & .sorting-tab {
        width: fit-content;
        min-width: 24px;
        padding: 0;
        border-left: unset;
      }

      & .component-task-item-body {
        padding-left: unset!important;
      }
      & .collapse {
        display: none;
      }
      & .component-task-item-number {
        display: none;
      }

      & .sorting-tab-deadline {
        //position: absolute;
      }

      & .sorting-tab-users {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        width: fit-content;
        padding-left: 12px;
      }

      & .item-title-wrap {
        max-width: calc(100% - 80px);
      }
    }
  }

  & .main-loading-block {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  &.task-content-editing {
    & .title-edit {
      user-select: text;
    }
  }

  & .show-more-component {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;

    & .card-task-number {
      width: fit-content;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin-right: 4px;
    }

    & .title-edit {
      display: flex;
      overflow-wrap: anywhere;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      align-content: flex-start;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      align-items: flex-start;
      word-break: break-all;
    }
  }

  &.no-draggable {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 600px;
    order: 99999999999999;
  }

  & .data-items-0 {
    display: none;
  }

  & .card-task-number {
    color: var(--blue);
    position: absolute;
  }

  &-actions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0 4px;

    &-second {
      /*display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;*/
      width: 100%;
      padding: 8px 0;

      & .task-info-element {
        border: unset;
        margin-right: 8px;
        width: fit-content;
        width: -moz-fit-content;
      }

      & .no-users-selected {
        &:hover {
          border: 0.5px dashed var(--blue);

          & path {
            fill: var(--blue);
          }
        }

        border: 0.5px dashed var(--black-60);

        & path {
          fill: var(--black-60);
        }
      }

      & .pseudo-hover {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;

        &[all="0"] {
          & > span {
            display: none;
          }
        }

        &:hover::before {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        &::before {
          opacity: 0;
          position: absolute;
          left: 50%;
          top: 50%;
          content: '';
          width: calc(100% + 12px);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          height: 24px;
          border-radius: 4px;
          background: var(--hover);
        }
      }

      & .priority {
        &-null {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      & .subs {
        &-null {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      & .deadline {
        &-null {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      & .users {
        &-null {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      & .component-avatar {
        border-radius: 4px;
      }

      & .component-task-actions-info {
        //display: none;
      }
    }

    &-three {
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;

      position: absolute;
      left: -1px;
      width: calc(100% + 2px);
      top: 98%;
      background: #eaeaea;
      z-index: 17;

      display: none;

      padding: 0 16px 8px 16px;

      border-left: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);
      border-bottom: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);
      border-right: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);

      box-sizing: border-box;
      box-shadow: 0 0.5px 0.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
        0 1.8px 3.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
      border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;;
    }

    &-subtasks {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      align-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      width: 100%;

      & .no-users-selected {
        &:hover {
          border: 0.5px dashed var(--blue);

          & path {
            fill: var(--blue);
          }
        }

        border: 0.5px dashed var(--black-60);

        & path {
          fill: var(--black-60);
        }
      }

      & .subtask {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;

        & space {
          position: absolute;
          height: 100%;
          right: 0;
          background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
        }

        & .subtask-actions {
          display: none;
          z-index: 100;

          & .task-info-element {
            border: unset;
            margin-left: 8px;
            width: fit-content;
            width: -moz-fit-content;
          }
        }

        &:hover {
          background: unset;

          &::before {
            display: flex;
          }

          & .subtask-actions {
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;

            &.inputt {
              right: -16px;
            }
          }

          & space {
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgb(246, 244, 244));
            min-width: 80px !important;
          }
        }

        &.closed, &.done {
          & .top {
            color: rgba(96, 94, 92, 1);
            text-decoration: line-through;
          }
        }

        & .content-block .top {
          text-overflow: unset;
        }

        &::before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          height: 100%;
          width: calc(100% + 32px);
          top: 0;
          left: -17px;
          background: var(--hover);
          display: none;
          border-right: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);
          border-left: 1px solid var(--stroke-opacity);
        }

        &.task-inp {
          position: relative;

          &:hover {
            &::before {
              display: none;
            }
          }

          & .input-area {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            border: unset;
            cursor: text;
            padding-top: 10px;

            &-wrap {
              position: unset;
            }

            &::after {
              display: none;
              width: 113.5%;
              height: 100%;
              top: 0;
              left: -17px;
              content: '';
              position: absolute;

              border-top: 1px solid var(--blue);
              border-bottom: 1px solid var(--blue);
            }

            &:focus {
              &::after {
                display: flex;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    & .more-no-visible {
      display: none;
    }

    &.more-items {
      & .tager {
        display: none;
      }

      & .more-no-visible {
        background: var(--black-60);
        display: flex;
        color: var(--white);
      }

      & .tager:nth-child(1) {
        display: flex;
      }

      & .tager:nth-child(2) {
        display: flex;
      }

      & .tager:nth-child(3) {
        display: flex;
      }
    }

    & > .tager {
      margin-right: 4px;
      color: var(--white);
    }
  }

  &.selected {
    background: var(--hover);
    & .data-items-0 {
      display: flex;
    }
  }

  & .hover:hover {
    background: var(--hover);
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  & .icon-16 {
    & svg {
      width: 16px !important;
      height: 16px !important;
    }
  }

  & .show-more-component {
    overflow-wrap: anywhere;
  }

  &-placeholder {
    background: var(--hover);
    border-radius: 4px;
  }

  &:hover {
    &.dragged {
      background: var(--white);
    }

    background: var(--hover);
    z-index: 18;

    & .component-task-actions-info {
      display: flex;
    }

    & .component-card-task-actions {
      padding: 16px 0 4px !important;
    }

    & .component-card-task-actions-second {
      padding: 8px 0 !important;
    }

    & .component-card-task-actions-three {
      display: flex;
    }

    & .data-items-0 {
      display: flex;
    }

    & .moreOptionsFromCard {
      display: unset;
    }
  }

  & .task-column-element-priority {
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 24px;
  }

  & .task-info-line-item-files, & .task-info-line-item-subtask, & .task-info-line-item-comment {
    height: 24px;
  }

  & .component-card-task-actions .task-column-element-tags {
    border-left: 0;
  }
}

.task-right-block.hide-id .title-edit {
  text-indent: unset!important;
}

.icon-16 {
  & svg {
    width: 16px !important;
    height: 16px !important;
  }
}
```

Пример элемента:

```
<div class="component-card-task" data-work-id="3724" data-status-id="1107" data-project-id="586" data-space-id="402"><div class="show-more-component"><span class="card-task-number">#5</span> <div class="title-edit" style="text-indent: calc(17.4062px + 4px)">1.2</div></div><div class="component-card-task-actions py-0"><div class="task-info-element task-column-element-tags with-more data-items-0"><div class="task-info-select-button task-info-select-button-tags"><div class="task-info-element-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M11.8778 5.12396C12.445 5.12396 12.9048 4.66514 12.9048 4.09917C12.9048 3.53319 12.445 3.07437 11.8778 3.07437C11.3106 3.07437 10.8508 3.53319 10.8508 4.09917C10.8508 4.66514 11.3106 5.12396 11.8778 5.12396Z" fill="black"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.92949 4.40949e-05C8.38098 -0.00354364 7.85382 0.211934 7.46547 0.598465L0.60346 7.42822C-0.200429 8.22834 -0.201259 9.52748 0.601608 10.3286L5.68366 15.3997C6.48581 16.2001 7.78634 16.2001 8.58848 15.3997L15.3984 8.60449C15.7843 8.21938 16.0008 7.69683 16 7.1522L15.9925 2.07941C15.9908 0.953883 15.0799 0.0402749 13.9519 0.0328969L8.92949 4.40949e-05ZM8.19075 1.32402C8.38492 1.13076 8.64851 1.02302 8.92276 1.02481L13.9452 1.05767C14.5092 1.06136 14.9647 1.51816 14.9655 2.08092L14.973 7.15371C14.9734 7.42602 14.8652 7.6873 14.6722 7.87986L7.86228 14.6751C7.4612 15.0753 6.81094 15.0753 6.40987 14.6751L1.32781 9.60398C0.926381 9.20341 0.926795 8.55384 1.32874 8.15378L8.19075 1.32402Z" fill="black"></path></svg></div></div></div></div><div class="component-card-task-actions-second"><div class="component-task-actions-info"><div class="info-left"><div class="task-info-element task-column-element-users info-users data-items-0"><div class="task-info-select-button task-info-select-button-user" data-tooltip="Assignee"><div class="task-info-element-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 14 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M7 0C4.79086 0 3 1.79086 3 4C3 6.20914 4.79086 8 7 8C9.20914 8 11 6.20914 11 4C11 1.79086 9.20914 0 7 0ZM4 4C4 2.34315 5.34315 1 7 1C8.65685 1 10 2.34315 10 4C10 5.65685 8.65685 7 7 7C5.34315 7 4 5.65685 4 4Z" fill="black"></path><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M2.00873 9C0.903151 9 0 9.88687 0 11C0 12.6912 0.83281 13.9663 2.13499 14.7966C3.41697 15.614 5.14526 16 7 16C8.85474 16 10.583 15.614 11.865 14.7966C13.1672 13.9663 14 12.6912 14 11C14 9.89557 13.1045 9.00001 12 9.00001L2.00873 9ZM1 11C1 10.4467 1.44786 10 2.00873 10L12 10C12.5522 10 13 10.4478 13 11C13 12.3088 12.3777 13.2837 11.3274 13.9534C10.2568 14.636 8.73511 15 7 15C5.26489 15 3.74318 14.636 2.67262 13.9534C1.62226 13.2837 1 12.3088 1 11Z" fill="black"></path></svg></div><div class="task-info-executors-block"></div></div></div><div class="task-info-element task-column-element-deadline data-items-0" data-tooltip="Due Date"><div class="task-info-select-button task-info-select-button-deadline"><div class="task-info-element-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.2273 0C11.2063 0 12 0.793677 12 1.77273V10.2273C12 11.2063 11.2063 12 10.2273 12H1.77273C0.793677 12 0 11.2063 0 10.2273V1.77273C0 0.793677 0.793677 0 1.77273 0H10.2273ZM10 3.54709H2V2.72891H10V3.54709ZM0.818182 2.72891V1.77273C0.818182 1.24555 1.24555 0.818182 1.77273 0.818182H10.2273C10.7545 0.818182 11.1818 1.24555 11.1818 1.77273V2.72891V3.54709V10.2273C11.1818 10.7545 10.7545 11.1818 10.2273 11.1818H1.77273C1.24555 11.1818 0.818182 10.7545 0.818182 10.2273V3.54709V2.72891ZM3.1357 7.90986C3.51225 7.90986 3.81752 8.21512 3.81752 8.59168C3.81752 8.96824 3.51225 9.2735 3.1357 9.2735C2.75914 9.2735 2.45388 8.96824 2.45388 8.59168C2.45388 8.21512 2.75914 7.90986 3.1357 7.90986Z" fill="#000000"></path></svg></div></div></div></div><div class="info-right"><div class="task-info-line-item task-info-line-item-comment info-comments data-items-1" data-tooltip="Comments"><div class="task-info-line-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.36064 8.6738H10.05C10.7221 8.6738 11.25 8.10302 11.25 7.42114V2.05266C11.25 1.37078 10.7221 0.8 10.05 0.8H1.95C1.27787 0.8 0.75 1.37078 0.75 2.05266V7.42114C0.75 8.10302 1.27787 8.6738 1.95 8.6738H3.14931L3.15 11.2L3.1526 11.1998L3.15376 11.1991L6.36064 8.6738ZM3.59921 11.8427C3.26751 12.1038 2.7975 12.0325 2.54941 11.6833C2.45241 11.5468 2.4 11.3809 2.4 11.2106L2.39953 9.4738H1.95C0.873045 9.4738 0 8.55479 0 7.42114V2.05266C0 0.919006 0.873045 0 1.95 0H10.05C11.127 0 12 0.919006 12 2.05266V7.42114C12 8.55479 11.127 9.4738 10.05 9.4738H6.60749L3.59921 11.8427Z" fill="#000000"></path></svg></div><div class="task-info-line-text-block task-info-line-text-comment"><div class="task-info-line-text">1</div></div></div><div class="task-info-line-item task-info-line-item-files info-files data-items-0 empty-task-info-line-item" data-tooltip="Files"><div class="task-info-line-icon"><svg id="Слой_1" data-name="Слой 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 503.42 559"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#020202;}</style></defs><title>file</title><path class="cls-1" d="M445,117c5.88,1.26,11.81,2.36,17.65,3.81,58.81,14.58,99.12,68.35,96.07,128.76-1.62,32.16-13.69,60.12-36.52,83Q409.54,445.47,296.57,558.06c-24.76,24.59-55,32.11-88.29,21.61s-53.62-34.1-59.88-68.37c-5.3-29,2.73-55.09,23.55-76.08Q264.36,342,357.46,249.52c7-6.95,15.81-8.54,23.69-4.34s11.62,12.55,9.88,21.56c-.9,4.66-3.77,8-7,11.24Q292.44,369.51,200.9,461.1c-18.94,19-20.39,46.73-3.65,66.93,17,20.49,49.17,23.26,68.78,5.23,13.73-12.62,26.64-26.14,39.84-39.33Q400.47,399.39,495,304.79c27-27,34.06-64.46,18.84-99.34-23.66-54.24-98-69-139.95-27.25Q251.43,300,129.63,422.51c-44.65,45-45.61,122.37-3,169.62,50.5,56,133,58.2,186.36,4.88q101.46-101.46,202.9-203c5.73-5.74,12.39-7.79,20-5.62s12.11,7.37,13.65,15.08c1.26,6.33-.68,11.82-4.76,16.64-1.07,1.27-2.33,2.38-3.51,3.56Q440.16,524.82,339,625.91q-51.64,51.52-124.73,49.44c-1.11,0-2.4-.55-3.3.65h-2c-.39-1.36-1.57-.94-2.47-1A199.45,199.45,0,0,1,182.43,671c-67.48-15.24-120.84-76.3-126.32-144.78q-6.33-79.1,49.77-135.33L343.11,153.85a124.79,124.79,0,0,1,62.63-34.07c4.08-.9,8.45-.66,12.25-2.78Z" transform="translate(-55.46 -117)"></path></svg></div><div class="task-info-line-text-block"><div class="task-info-line-text"></div></div></div><div class="task-info-line-item task-info-line-item-subtask data-items-3" data-tooltip="Create subtask"><div class="task-info-line-icon"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M2.52174 3C2.80989 3 3.04348 3.23359 3.04348 3.52174V6.24392H10.076C10.3049 5.39374 11.0812 4.76801 12.0037 4.76801C13.1062 4.76801 14 5.66176 14 6.76426C14 7.86677 13.1062 8.76052 12.0037 8.76052C11.0823 8.76052 10.3066 8.13616 10.0767 7.2874H3.04348V11.2346H10.0761C10.3052 10.3847 11.0814 9.75918 12.0037 9.75918C13.1062 9.75918 14 10.6529 14 11.7554C14 12.8579 13.1062 13.7517 12.0037 13.7517C11.0821 13.7517 10.3063 13.1271 10.0766 12.278H2.52174C2.23359 12.278 2 12.0444 2 11.7563V3.52174C2 3.23359 2.23359 3 2.52174 3ZM12.0037 7.71704C12.5299 7.71704 12.9565 7.29047 12.9565 6.76426C12.9565 6.23806 12.5299 5.81149 12.0037 5.81149C11.4775 5.81149 11.051 6.23806 11.051 6.76426C11.051 7.29047 11.4775 7.71704 12.0037 7.71704ZM12.9565 11.7554C12.9565 12.2816 12.5299 12.7082 12.0037 12.7082C11.4775 12.7082 11.051 12.2816 11.051 11.7554C11.051 11.2292 11.4775 10.8027 12.0037 10.8027C12.5299 10.8027 12.9565 11.2292 12.9565 11.7554Z" fill="#605E5C"></path></svg></div><div class="task-info-line-text-block"><span class="task-info-line-text-2">3/</span><div class="task-info-line-text">3</div></div><div class="placeholder-component flex align-center just-center xx-small pointer"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M10.5 8L5.5 12L5.5 4L10.5 8Z" fill="#605E5C"></path></svg></div></div><div class="task-info-element task-column-element-priority info-priority data-items-0" data-tooltip="Priority"><div class="task-info-select-button task-info-select-button-priority"><div class="task-info-element-icon"><svg width="14" height="16" viewBox="0 0 14 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.04994 9.81818V1.09091H12.5233L10.0551 5.16392C9.94749 5.34153 9.94749 5.56756 10.0551 5.74517L12.5233 9.81818H1.04994ZM1.04994 10.9091H13.4742C13.8873 10.9091 14.1385 10.4362 13.9184 10.073L11.1197 5.45455L13.9184 0.83608C14.1385 0.472849 13.8873 0 13.4742 0H0.524968C0.235036 0 0 0.244208 0 0.545455V15.4545C0 15.7558 0.235036 16 0.524968 16C0.8149 16 1.04994 15.7558 1.04994 15.4545V10.9091Z" fill="black"></path><path d="M1.04994 9.81818V1.09091H12.5233L10.0551 5.16392C9.94749 5.34153 9.94749 5.56756 10.0551 5.74517L12.5233 9.81818H1.04994Z" fill="black"></path></svg></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="component-card-task-actions-three"><div class="moreOptionsFromCard component-task-actions-info"><div class="info-left"></div><div class="info-right"><div class="placeholder-component flex align-center just-center closedButton hover small pointer" data-tooltip="Complete task" data-active="1107"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M13.8639 3.65706C14.0533 3.85802 14.0439 4.17446 13.8429 4.36386L5.91309 11.8378C5.67573 12.0615 5.30311 12.0546 5.07417 11.8222L2.39384 9.1019C2.20003 8.9052 2.20237 8.58863 2.39907 8.39482C2.59578 8.20101 2.91235 8.20335 3.10616 8.40005L5.51192 10.8417L13.1571 3.63614C13.358 3.44674 13.6745 3.45611 13.8639 3.65706Z" fill="#605E5C"></path></svg></div><div class="placeholder-component flex align-center just-center hover ml-2 optionsButton small pointer" data-tooltip="More options"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M5 8C5 8.55229 4.55228 9 4 9C3.44772 9 3 8.55229 3 8C3 7.44772 3.44772 7 4 7C4.55228 7 5 7.44772 5 8Z" fill="#000000"></path><path d="M9 8C9 8.55229 8.55229 9 8 9C7.44772 9 7 8.55229 7 8C7 7.44772 7.44772 7 8 7C8.55229 7 9 7.44772 9 8Z" fill="#000000"></path><path d="M12 9C12.5523 9 13 8.55229 13 8C13 7.44772 12.5523 7 12 7C11.4477 7 11 7.44772 11 8C11 8.55229 11.4477 9 12 9Z" fill="#000000"></path></svg></div></div></div></div><div class="component-card-task-actions-subtasks w-100" style="display: none;"><div class="component-item-list w-100 border-bottom-1 no-hover"><div class="content-block"><div class="top hidden"></div><div class="bottom hidden"></div></div><div class="rr-block"></div></div><div class="w-100" style="position: relative; height: 60px;">
    <div class="main-loading-block">
        <div class="sub-loading">
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div></div><div class="component-item-list subtask"><div class="left-block mr-12"><div class="placeholder-component flex align-center just-center x-small"><svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7.91012 3.00806L8 3C8.24546 3 8.44961 3.17688 8.49194 3.41012L8.5 3.5V7.5H12.5C12.7455 7.5 12.9496 7.67688 12.9919 7.91012L13 8C13 8.24546 12.8231 8.44961 12.5899 8.49194L12.5 8.5H8.5V12.5C8.5 12.7455 8.32312 12.9496 8.08988 12.9919L8 13C7.75454 13 7.55039 12.8231 7.50806 12.5899L7.5 12.5V8.5H3.5C3.25454 8.5 3.05039 8.32312 3.00806 8.08988L3 8C3 7.75454 3.17688 7.55039 3.41012 7.50806L3.5 7.5H7.5V3.5C7.5 3.25454 7.67688 3.05039 7.91012 3.00806L8 3L7.91012 3.00806Z" fill="#605E5C"></path></svg></div></div><div class="content-block"><div class="top"><span>Add subtask</span></div><div class="bottom hidden"></div></div><div class="rr-block"></div></div></div></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже на баг в графическом движке браузера.
Попробуйте добавить стиль `outline: 1px solid transparent` к карточке.

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17822836/5698975

Comment: Не помогло. Добавил HTML код, чтобы вы могли сами протестировать.

Comment: @SireIMPACTUS, осталось добавить Safari, чтоб я мог сам потестировать =D